# How to change Progress bar image in android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I would like to change the progress bar to a custom drawable. How do I change the image of the progress bar?

Comment: big pain for me as well . answer requested .

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here my answer, i use my image in android progress bar..

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/my_progress_indeterminate" />
```

my_progress_indeterminate.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/animation" 
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"/>
```

animation.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/load" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/load" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/load" android:duration="50" />
     <rotate 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
         android:drawable="@drawable/load" 
         android:pivotX="50%" 
         android:pivotY="50%" 
         android:fromDegrees="330" 
         android:toDegrees="360" 
         android:repeatCount="1" />     

</animation-list>
```

Comment: what is  android:drawable="@drawable/load" ?

Comment: it's a drawable image load.png  @itzhar

Comment: where do you use animatio.xml ?

Comment: @hamid in my_progress_indeterminate.xml

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class by extending `ImageView` and use it like following in a similar way to `ProgressBar` with a rotation animation.

```
class CustomProgressBar : AppCompatImageView {

constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributeSet)

constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr)

private var anim: RotateAnimation? = null

init {
    setImageResource(R.drawable.your_custom_drawable)
    anim = RotateAnimation(
        0f, 350f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f
    )
    anim!!.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
    anim!!.repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE
    anim!!.duration = 1000
    startAnimation(anim)
}

fun getRotateAnimation(): RotateAnimation? {
    return anim
}}
```

And in your layout.xml just use this class as your ProgressBar

```
            <com.example.CustomProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/customProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

And in your fragment or activity show or hide it like following:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    customProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.customProgressBar)
}

fun showCustomProgressBar() {
    customProgressBar.visibility = VISIBLE
    customProgressBar.startAnimation(customProgressBar.getRotateAnimation())
}

fun hideCustomProgressBar() {
    customProgressBar.visibility = GONE
    customProgressBar.clearAnimation()
}
```