# Change the image of the progress bar in android

Tags: android, android-image, android-progressbar, android-drawable

I am the beginner to the android. I want to change the progress bar of my custom
How to change image of the progress bar.Please help me.Thanks in advance...

Comment: check out [the link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14644174/2345913)

Comment: check out my blog here http://pankajchunchun.wordpress.com/2011/09/10/customization-of-spinner-progress/

Comment: In my apps I'm using AsyncTask to display a progress bar.In this there is no <progress bar> tag in xml file .So how can i change progress bar image ..please give some idea to change the image

Answer (score 0):

A Custom ProgressBar for Android can be found here

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/custom-progressbar-for-android.html